# Perl formatting not working

Tags: perl, string-formatting

I have number line in my perl code that compute difference between 2 variable

```
$diff = $upper- $lower;
```

The value in variable upper and lower can be decimal, fractional and exponential.

When I print this difference to file, I want to preserve the format but want to truncate fractional value after 3 decimal places. How can I do this ?

e.g in different cases,

```
$diff =0.345664; I want to print as 0.346

$diff= 65.9787e-6; I want to print as 65.979e-06.
```

Can someone help me how to do this ? I was using `%.3f` But obviously it mess up with exponential numbers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exponential numbers"?

Comment: @melpomene: I assume he means *exponential notation*, i.e. `65E-1` instead of `6.5`. Maybe the values are strings

Comment: I'm guessing you mean 6.59787, not 65.9787?  Perl wouldn't produce the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the other answers, it sounds to me like what you want is simply to use `%.3g`, which will keep 3 significant figures but then discard any trailing `0`s.  The format perl by default uses to stringify a number is often `%.15g`.

```
perl -e'printf "%.3g\n", $_ for 0.345664, 0.349876, 65.9787e-6, 6.59123e-5'
0.346
0.35
6.6e-05
6.59e-05
```

Comment: Why do you think `6.6e-05` is ok when the OP said "I want to print as `65.979e-06`."

Comment: @ikegami because I think that was an error.  I think the "I want to preserve the format" means simply do what perl normally does to stringify the number (and it is clear from the question we are talking about a number as input, not a string), but with only 3 significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
printf "%.3f\n", $diff;
```

and

```
printf "%.3e\n", $diff;
```

By the way, there are only *integer* and *floating point* numeric values in Perl

There is

```
$diff = 0.345664;

printf "%.3f\n", $diff;

$diff = 65.9787e-6;

printf "%.3e\n", $diff;
```

#### output

```
0.346
6.598e-005
```

There is no one format specifier that will provide both formats depending on the value of the variable -- you must write code to make the decision yourself

There is also no way to get `65.98e-006` instead of `6.598e-005` with the `%e` format. There is always a single non-zero digit before the decimal point

Comment: What about `%g`? If I write `perl -e 'printf "%.3g %.3g\n", 0.345664, 65.9787e-6;'` then I get `0.346 6.6e-05`, i.e. it _depends_ on the variable's value, but I couldn't figure out how exactly.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Yeah, I try to ignore `%g`. It's supposed to use either `%f` or `%e` format, depending on the size of the value, but as you see it produces `6.6e-05` for `%.3g` whereas `%.3e`  produces `6.598e-05`, so it's more than a little odd. Some documentation for the C library version says that `%g` also drops trailing zeroes whereas `%e` does not. In Perl it's particularly easy to pick the format you want according to the size of the value to be represented; you can even mess with the resultant string afterwards as **ikegami** shows in his answer.

Comment: @Borodin %.3g produces 6.6e-05 because it drop the trailing 0.  it is still keeping three decimal places.   with input 65.94e-6, it gives 6.59e-6.

Comment: @ysth: But that's *two* decimal places, not three! If it were rounding to three places it would produce the same result as the `%e` specifier. (Actually that may be a bug in Perl's `printf` code.) I don't see why `%g` should do anything different from `%e` at all; I can't think of a good reason why it even removes trailing zeroes when `%e` does not. And while I'm ranting, I think it's disgraceful that there's no specifier to generate *engineering* format, where the coefficient is zero or more and less than 1,000, while the exponent is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @Borodin no, it formats three significant digits, then removes trailing 0s

Answer (score -1):

```
sub format1 { sprintf "%.3f", $_[0] }

say format1(0.345664);  # 0.346
```

```
sub format2 {
   sprintf("%.4e", $_[0])
      =~ s/\.(.)/$1./sr
         =~ s/([+-]\d\d)\z/ sprintf("%+03d", $1-1) /aer
}

say format2(65.9787e-6);  # 65.979e-06
```